# Mesh shows up as wire frame in solid view

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I noticed that one of my meshes shows up as a wireframe even in solid view. Is there any way to fix this without having to remake the object? It renders it as a solid.

[.blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/2d4069a49bf24116808d0f7b75e56225)

[image]

Comment: You have it set to display as wire in properties/object data/viewport display/display as.